# Issue with retrieving Campaign recordtype Id

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, lwc-wire-adapter, campaign

I'm having some issues to retrieve campaign recordtype id inside the lwc

```
import CAMPAIGN_RECORDTYPEID from"@salesforce/schema/Campaign.RecordTypeId";

@wire(getRecord, {​​​​​​​​​​​​​ recordId:"$campId", fields: [CAMPAIGN_RECORDTYPEID] }​​​​​​​​​​​​​)
campaign;

getcurrentCampaignRecordType(){​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
return getFieldValue(this.campaign.data, CAMPAIGN_RECORDTYPEID);
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This is where I'm trying to validate the record type id, sometimes it retrieves the id, sometimes retrieves "undefined"

[image]

Edited

Comment: how is that code in the image invoked? are you certain that wire promise resolved by then?

Comment: @wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID,  fields: [PROFILE_NAME]})
  userProfile2({data,error}){
    if(data){
      this.record = data;
      this.currentUserProfName = getFieldValue(this.record, PROFILE_NAME); //aleo.cris.buiza created this variable
      this.makeFormReadOnly();
    } else if (error){
      this.error=error;
    } 
  }

Comment: It's getting called from another wire

Comment: order of wire execution is not guaranteed. What you need to do is store data in variables and in both wire callbacks call resolution method that should check that both are set and only act if so

Comment: Your first comment was enough for me to realize the execution order was not guaranteed, thanks alot!